# Go-playground validator: How to validate json string

Tags: go, validation

With https://github.com/go-playground/validator, I can validate a struct, but if I want to ensure my json string is valid, how can I do it?

---

I could say I just do something like:

```
type User struct {
    Username string `json:"username" validate:"required"`
    Age      int    `json:"age" validate:"required,gte=0"`
}

func main() {
    jsonStr := `{ "username": "123455", "age": "12" }`
    user := User{}
    jsonBytes := []byte(jsonStr)
    if !json.Valid(jsonBytes) {
        log.Fatal("input is not a valid json")
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, &user)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    log.Print(user)
    validate := validator.New()
    err = validate.Struct(user)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }
    log.Print("valid")
}
```

Notice that the JSON string does not have a valid type for age thus this will throw even b4 we can parse the json into the struct for the `validate.Struct` function can work:

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field User.age of type int
```

Is there a better way to validate if the JSON string is valid right from the start?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are looking for an implementation of something like [json-schema](https://json-schema.org/). If that is the case, then neither `encoding/json` nor `playground/validator` will help, one can only validate JSON as per [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html), the other can only validate Go values. There are json-schema implementations on github, use its search to look for them and choose whichever you like best.